# How to give name and id to a button in android studio without going to xml file?

Tags: android-studio

How do I change the attributes of the button  without going to the XML file or the attributes of the button, I see people   using shortcut to change the id and name of the button but don't know what it is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7NDd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvvI9.png)
How to change name and id as  shown the picture 2

Comment: on the preview, if you click the element, in the menu on the right there are those fields which can be filled in with your value

Comment: I know that ,but I want  to change it without going there

Comment: and from where you want to change it?

Comment: just by clicking it on the button

Answer (score 0):

You'll see an "attributes" panel on the right of the window like this [image: attribute closed]

click on it to open, then click on the view you want to edit, in your case the button. You'll see something like this[image: attribute open]

Comment: You're welcome. I just saw the second image you uploaded and unfortunately I don't know how to do that. Good luck finding the solution to your problem.